# Managing WildFly deployable datasources

Tags: datasource, jboss7.x, wildfly

I have managed to deploy a deployable datasource based on this [post](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-datasource/jboss-as-7-deployable-datasources). However the drawback is it cannot be managed or monitored using the management console.

Are there any plans to have these datasources managed using the CLI or Admin Console? We have multiple applications installed on a single instance with different datasources and like to manage or at least getting usage metrics from the management console or CLI.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans to add support for that in near future. 
Best to move datasources configuration to standalone.xml to get management capabilities.

Deployable data sources are primary meant for development process.

see [WildFly documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration) on how to configure datasources that can be manageable via admin console / CLI / rest

Comment: I think the JBoss/WildFly development team are not considering(downplaying) the importance of deployable datasources. We currently have about 10 nodes/instances running of a single JBoss 5.1.0 installation; running multiple applications per node. Having deployable datasources simplifies support and adding of new applications and their datasources. Having all configs in one file introduces a single point of failure, if the config fails the whole node is affected. Before this was isolated.

Answer (score -1):

@n002213f is a bit later to answer, but i'm trying to do the same thing. And i've discovered that is possible to create datasource on deploy.
**Not using a datasource definition file**, i.e: `mylink-ds.xml`.
With this system you are creating the datasource like if you define one in admin console.

I've found a blog post here: [Wildfly deploy datasources and jdbc driver automatically](https://javavolker.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/automated-jdbc-driver-and-datasource-deployment-with-wildfly-8/)

and here, the usage page of wildlfy plugin: [Wildfly plugin usage complex example](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/complex-example.html)

Comment: sure it's possible. This question was asking about managing them.

Comment: Sincerely i've not tried, but reading the example on blog article, the deploy process use the cli command to create the datasource. With this assumptoin i think the datasource can be managed by admin console